# Replacing current div with jquery result

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to get latest data for a div and trying to replace it. The ajax query fetches the entire html page. Out of which I am finding `right div`. Now I need to replace current `right div` with what I have received.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: dataArray,
            
            success: function (data) {        
                var content = $(data).find('.right');
                $(".right").html(content[0])
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
```

It works but the result data has some weird layout issues. What is the proper way to setting the div.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS, as well as the response from the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecing the element and putting it inside of it, not replacing it.

```
var content = $(data).find('.right');
$(".right").html(content[0]);
```

So your output looks like

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="right">
    <p>New content</p>
  <div>
<div>
```

Either set the html

```
$(".right").html(content.html())
```

or replace it

```
$(".right").replaceWith(content)
```

Comment: for some reason, javascript functions are not working anymore. would there be any specific reason? i have tried both replaceWith and .html(

Comment: Because when you replace the content it replaces the content. It is like erasing the whiteboard and redrawing everything. Events are no longer bound because the original elements you attached it to are blown away.